# Your First Mac App -- Compiler Can't see updateUserInterface

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, methods

i am in middle of [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/05_CompletingAppDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611-CH8-SW1) tutorial for Mac OS X developers and i am experiencing problem with updateUserInterface. I've followed the tutorial, which produces following codes of AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

( https://gist.github.com/1599797 )

**What am I doing wrong? The code seems to me OK.**

( This is my first mac developing. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a closer look at the method call. The problem is from a (nonexistent) method called `updateUserInteface`, not `updateUserInterface`.

Comment: Michael J. Barber: Thank you. I would down vote the question if i could